# How to save blob with huggingface.js

Tags: node.js, huggingface

I'm trying to run the following example generating image from text with the inference API from:

https://huggingface.co/docs/huggingface.js/index

The API succeeds, but I' having trouble saving the image to the local filesystem.

```
 const blob = await inference.textToImage({
        model: 'stabilityai/stable-diffusion-2',
        inputs: 'award winning high resolution photo of a giant tortoise/((ladybird)) hybrid, [trending on artstation]',
        parameters: {
            negative_prompt: 'blurry',
        }
    })

    console.log('Received:', blob)
    const fileName = 'generated_image.jpg'
    blob.stream().pipe(fs.createWriteStream(fileName))
     .on('finish', () => console.log('finished'))
     .on('error', e => console.log('Error:', e))
```

Output:

```
Received: Blob { size: 130079, type: 'image/jpeg' }

Blob.stream(...).pipe is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

By converting the response from haggingface, you can turn it into a buffer using the arrayBuffer function

```
const buffer = await blob.arrayBuffer()
```

And then save the buffer wherever you want. for this example I saved it as a file on my machine

```js
import { writeFile } from 'fs/promises'
import { join, resolve } from 'path'

//...

const blob = await inference.textToImage({
      model: 'stabilityai/stable-diffusion-2',
      inputs: 'award winning high resolution photo of a giant tortoise/((ladybird)) hybrid, [trending on artstation]',
      parameters: {
          negative_prompt: 'blurry',
      }
  })
const buffer = await blob.arrayBuffer()
const fileExt = result.type.split('/')[1]
const fileName = `${Date.now().toString()}.${fileExt}`
const filePath = resolve(join(currentDir, fileName))
// Saving image
await writeFile(filePath, Buffer.from(buffer))
```